# Localization at run time for iOS app

Tags: ios, localization

I want to change my app language at runtime. For that I had implemented the category class like

.h file.

```
@interface NSBundle (Language)

+ (void)setLanguage:(NSString *)language;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static const char _bundle=0;

@interface BundleEx : NSBundle
@end

@implementation BundleEx

- (NSString *)localizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value table:(NSString *)tableName
{
    NSBundle *bundle = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &_bundle);
    return bundle ? [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:value table:tableName] : [super localizedStringForKey:key value:value table:tableName];
}

@end
@implementation NSBundle (Language)

+ (void)setLanguage:(NSString *)language
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^
                  {
                      object_setClass([NSBundle mainBundle],[BundleEx class]);
                  });
    objc_setAssociatedObject([NSBundle mainBundle], &_bundle, language ? [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:language ofType:@"lproj"]] : nil, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"changeLanguage" object:self];
}
```

and at button click change the language like `[NSBundle setLanguage:langCode];`
 
but now I am bit confusing that what should I write to set label text like

```
lbl.text = ?
```

because it still need to restart my app to show effect of language .

Answer (score 0):

iOS already have a localization file for multiple languages, you can find it in Localization/Localizable.strings.

In Localizable.strings (English)

```
"text" = "This is a text";
```

Then, put your setting text code in a function. So that, you can redraw the text after switching language.

```
func loadText() {
    lbl.text = String.localizedString("text")
}

func changeLanguage() { // Change Language Notification
    loadText()
}
```

Comment: i want to chage whole app laguage not for only one viewcontroller.

Comment: So sad to say that you cannot change text for all view controller in your app. But you can put the loadText function in viewWillAppear of every view controller.

Comment: i think it's possible. as you can see in my question it possible but i have to restart the app.